# Drupal 7 with Webform: how to display warning message, when clicking upload, and no file is chosen?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I have a webform, in which I have file upload.

However, when user chooses no file, he is still able to click upload and nothing happens. I would like to have there similar message like when he chooses file with extension which is not allowed. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should just set up file field in webform as required. There you can set up allowed extension user can upload.

[image]

Then you have default Drupal warning messages if user don't select file to upload or select file with not allowed extension.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to set this field as required - I just want to have notice message. Besides, even I set it as required, it still doesn't give that notice when clicking "upload" button, but when you click submit

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy UI option to do this but you could add a JS handler which checks to see if the file is chosen when the button is clicked. I think the variable you are looking for will be in the $form_state array. You should be able to see it with a debugger or with dpm();